# PYTHONPATH permissions

Tags: python

I've copied a few modules from the standard `site-packages` location on my windows pc into an EC2 ubuntu instance's user's home directory: `/home/theuser/data/projects/mypack`.

`mypack` contains

1) one empty `__init__.py` and

2) one subdirectory `mymodules`, in which I have my python module files along with one `__init__.py` that runs the `from thefile import thefile` statements.

I've made sure to edit both `.bashrc` and `.profile` for `theuser` in order to update `PYTHONPATH`. And I made sure to start a fresh session, logged in as `theuser`.

`import mypack` runs fine if I'm in `/home/theuser/data/projects`. Anywhere else, say in `theuser`'s home directory, I get

```
>>> import mypack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named mypack
```

I'm not that familiar with unix permissions, and the setup above tested OK on my pc. Is some unix permission detail tripping me up?

`PYTHONPATH` does seems to register the change properly:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.48-py2.7.egg', 
'/home/theuser', 
'/home/theuser/data/projects/mypack', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Thanks.

```
theuser@ip-12-345-67-8:~/data/projects$ ls -lah
total 20K
drwxrwxr-x 5 theuser theuser 4.0K Jul  2 18:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 theuser theuser 4.0K Jul  2 16:48 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 theuser theuser 4.0K Jul  2 17:18 database
drwxrwxr-x 2 theuser theuser 4.0K Jul  2 18:28 analysis
drwxrwxr-x 5 theuser theuser 4.0K Jul  2 19:18 mypack
```

Comment: could you post the output of `ls -lah` inside /home/theuser/data/projects?

Comment: I always reccomand to put (or symlink) such packages in the user-site directory (shown by `python -m site --user-site`). It's in sys.path by default, so spares you to mess around with PYTHONPATH, .profile and .bashrc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` should contain `/home/theuser/data/projects`, not `/home/theuser/data/projects/mypack`.

When you ask Python to `import mypack`, it looks for either `mypack.py` or a directory `mypack` containing `__init__.py` using its search path.

This works when you're inside `.../projects`, because `mypack/__init__.py` is available there (and the `''` entry in `sys.path` searches the current working directory), but when you're not, it cannot find `mypack/__init__.py` with the `PYTHONPATH` you've supplied.

Comment: It worked when he was inside .../projects because PYTHONPATH contains '', which will cause current directory to be included when looking for modules.  If that was removed from PYTHONPATH, then he wouldn't have been able to load mypack from that directory either.

Comment: @rread A good point (which I added to my answer), though not strictly correct—`''` is part of `sys.path`, not the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  Observe the output of `PYTHONPATH=foo python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to have "/home/theuser/data/projects" in your PYTHONPATH, instead of "/home/theuser/data/projects/mypack".